# the script in frame B can't refer to the Window object for frame A

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have three file. First is index.html, second is frame1.html and third is frame2.html.

In index.html i have code:

```
<iframe src="frameA.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="frameB.html"></iframe>
```

In frameA:

```
<script>
var n = 3;
</script>
```

In frameB:

```
console.log(parent[0].n)// undefined why?
```

In frameB i get msg undefined but when i run console.log(parent[0]) i get window frameA. Why i cant get value from frameA to frameB?

Comment: A isn't parent of B is why, those iframes are siblings

Comment: but parent[0] is frameA window object ;p

Comment: not the way you have shown it with the html

Comment: parent === object window(index.html) but parent[0] === object window frame A

Comment: that makes no sense. `parent` is an object so there is no `parent[0]`

Comment: parent[0] is object window of frameA. I sure

Comment: window.frames[0].parent === window  // always true

Comment: what relevance does that have?

Comment: so why i cant get N ?

Comment: because the frames are siblings unless the html shown is wrong

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox it works like a charm. In Chromium/Chrome access to `n` is blocked by [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing
>   a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

If you upload your example to any server or set up a localhost, it will work fine in Chromium, too (tested it on a local apache2).

Maybe Chromium stumbles on that empty `window.location.hostname` while working over `file://`-protocol.

Comment: so why it has access to parent[0] ??//() window of frame A